# Probability of basketball shots in a row

Tags: probability, statistics

I've read some of the answer with this related question but it's not somewhat the answer I'm looking for.

A player has a $75\%$ free throw percentage. Can someone explain to me why the probability of shooting $10$ consecutive shots would be $0,75^{10}$?

Comment: Let $A_i$ be the event of the ith successful shot. The events a are independent. Therefore $P(A_1\cap A_2 \cap \ldots \cap A_{10})=P(A_1)\cdot P(A_2)\cdot \ldots P(A_{10})$   And $P(A_i)=0.75 \forall \ i$ Thus we get $(P(A_i))^{10}=0.75^{10}$

Comment: It assumes independence, so no "hot hand" or things like that

Answer (score 1):

Everytime the person throws, he has a 0.75 chance of scoring.

So when he throws 2 times, he needs to score on the first throw (0.75) and on the second throw (0.75 again). The probability of that happening is $0.75 \cdot 0.75 = 0.75^2$.

Now you can cascade this for any amount of consecutive throws.